# Clicking image change imput field from an array

Tags: javascript

I want to make the input value change when I click on an image. The image and the value are already in an array. The images are displayed through a "for loop" but when I click I want each image to get its own text from the array.
This is a code

```js
var i;

var items = [
  ['img1.jpg', 'car1', 'link1'],
  ['img2.jpg', 'car2', 'link2'],
  ['img3.jpg', 'car3', 'link3'],
  ['img4.jpg', 'car4', 'link4'],
];

var copyText = document.getElementById("text-copy");

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  var e = '<img class="img_game_selector" src="' + items[i][0] + '" tabindex="0" onclick="Linkcreator()"></div>';
  $(".image_container").append(e);

}

function Linkcreator() {
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    copyText.value = items[i][2];
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image_container mx-auto"></div>
<div class="copy-link">
  <input class="input-group bg-dark w-75 mx-auto" type="text" id="text-copy" name="copy-link-text" value="Link" onclick="myFunction()">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion of implementation that should be more readable.

```js
const items = [
  ['img1.jpg', 'car1', 'link1'],
  ['img2.jpg', 'car2', 'link2'],
  ['img3.jpg', 'car3', 'link3'],
  ['img4.jpg', 'car4', 'link4'],
];

const copyText = document.getElementById("text-copy");

for (const item of items) {
  const [src, car_nb, link] = item; // You can use destructuring to retrieve your array elements as named variables;
  const img = document.createElement("img"); // Use createElement to get a real JS object instead of an html string.
  img.setAttribute("src", src);
  img.setAttribute("link", link);
  img.onclick = linkCreator.bind(img); // Use bind to make that img the object (this) of the function when its called

  document.getElementById("image-container").appendChild(img);
}

function linkCreator() {
  // Here "this" is the clicked image
  copyText.value = this.getAttribute("link");
}
```

```html
<div id="image-container">

</div>
<div class="copy-link">
  <input id="text-copy">
</div>
```